# How to apply PS_BASE_URI to search module?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.4

I am building a search module for Prestashop. I am able to apply the `BASE_URI` onto my JS and CSS assets so they load fine.

I have an issue where if shops have set a `BASE_URI`, when they search on my search bar and hit enter, it still goes to `<domain>/?query_params`, but actually I need it to go to `<domain>/BASE_URI/?query_params`.

I'm not sure where to start, feels like I need to write some logic in my front controller but I can't seem to find any resources online to point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

To reach this behavior you need to change action for the search form. If you use PS 1.7 you can do that in `themes\yuor_theme\modules\ps_searchbar\ps_searchbar.tpl` in line `<form method="get" action="{$search_controller_url}">` put your url instead of `{$search_controller_url}`. If you use PS 1.6 that are files `themes\your_theme\modules\blocksearch\blocksearch-top.tpl` and `themes\your_theme\modules\blocksearch\blocksearch.tpl` and change an action there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, [complete list of PS variables](https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2018/04/constants-and-variables-for-prestashop/)

for a full variable list applicable to PS1.6 & 1.7.

It has a search box too so you can search for e.g. "base"